# Mongoose find inside nested schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In mongoose we are deeply searching inside a nested schema, without much success. Every time we run this function we always get an empty array returned.

```
function findAlarms(lastUpdate = new Date(0), record = Record) {

  // For docs on find http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html
  return record
    .find({
      // Date due must be less than "now"
      'documents.alarm.date_due': {
        $lte: Date.now(),
      },
      // Must be greater than the last update and less than "now"
      'documents.alarm.date_reminder.reminder': {
        $gte: lastUpdate,
        $lte: Date.now(),
      },
    })
    .populate('documents')
    .exec();
}
```

Our schemas, greatly summarized, look like this:

```
const RecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  documents: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Document',
    },
  ],
});
```

And our documents schema, similarly summarized looks like this:

```
const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  alarm: {
    date_due: { type: Date },
    date_reminder: [
      {
        reminder: { type: Date },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

This search returns no matching elements, even though we know there are documents that match. If we modify our `findAlarms` method to use the documents schema:

```
function findAlarms(lastUpdate = new Date(0), document = Document) {
  // For docs on find http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html
  return document
    .find({
      // Date due must be less than "now"
      'alarm.date_due': {
        $lte: Date.now(),
      },
      // Must be greater than the last update and less than "now"
      'alarm.date_reminder.reminder': {
        $gte: lastUpdate,
        $lte: Date.now(),
      },
    })
    .exec();
}
```

It will return all of our matching documents. However, having records is essential for our needs. Now, I could use a hack and then find records using the array of `document._id`s that return.

Nonetheless, I would love to know if there's an approach where we can find using the records directly, since adding that extra step feels really hacky, and this operation runs every 5 minutes so I'd love to be more efficient wherever posible.

Comment: You said: `This search returns no matching elements` and `It will return all of our matching documents` sorry, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The second example uses the Documents schema, rather than the Records schema.